# dynamic creation of buttons in a group

Tags: mfc

hi i want to create a 12 buttons dynamically,   6 button 40x40 pixels and 6 button size 60x60 pixels with two different groups (group 1 contains 6 buttons   and group 2 contains 6 buttons) with border.and i want to move groups within the dialog eg : MFC dialog window contains many controls and we can   easily move the dialog within the screen. same thing i want move the groups which contains buttons within the dialog.

i have created buttons dynamically in a dialog.but i have no idia how to create groups please   help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're talking about. Maybe a picture/sketch would help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, by "group" you mean a GroupBox. To create it dynamically you just create a `CButton` with the `BS_GROUPBOX` flag.

As for moving all the buttons at the same time, AFAIK this is not possible within the same funcion call; you must move each button/groupbox separately.